# Angular template reference variable for radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angular

I know about this:

```
<input type="text" #inp>
<button type="button" (click)="onClick(inp.value)">Click</button>
```

So I get the value I typed into textbox without having to use ngModel directive.

Is there any similar approach to work with radio buttons without having to use ngModel?

```
<input type="radio" value="selected" name="viewType">Selected
<input type="radio" value="unselected" name="viewType">Unselected
<input type="radio" value="both" name="viewType">Both
```

Below these radio buttons I have a refresh button like this:

```
<button (click)="refreshView()">Refresh</button>
```

These html input elements aren't part of any form tag. What I want is to have a "refreshView" function call with a parameter - the selected radio button value.

Is this possible?

Comment: It can probably be done but it would be easier with `ngModel`. Is there a reason for not using it?

Comment: Just to avoid creating an extra variable simply to hold the viewType which is not used anywhere else. "refreshView" function could do all the setup if it can get the correct viewType from the template.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have only a few radio buttons, the following syntax would work. It gets the value associated with the radio button that is checked, with the help of nested [conditional operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
<input #rad1 type="radio" value="selected" name="viewType" >Selected
<input #rad2 type="radio" value="unselected" name="viewType" >Unselected
<input #rad3 type="radio" value="both" name="viewType" >Both

<button (click)="refreshView(rad1.checked ? rad1.value : rad2.checked ? rad2.value : rad3.checked ? rad3.value : null)">Refresh</button>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tuydjw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: Yes, I have only these three options. Thank you this works great and for the demo and docs links.